# XCode code snippets in .m file. Limit scope? (other then all)

Tags: xcode, scope, code-snippets

I am trying to get a code snippet shortcut to **only work** in the interface section. As in:

```c
//  ViewController.m

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *str;

codeSnippetsShortcutHere...?

@end
```

This only works if the scope is set to 'all'. Trying to limit the scope in any way works random at best. (That is, it works once and then just not showing up).

Is there a specific scope for this section? *(Again, this is the .m file)*

-Edit: I should mention, this works perfectly in the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

This scope is named "Class interface methods", it works for me ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I should have emphasized in the "only works if the scope is set to 'all'", that I have tried to add **all scopes** and XCode could not find my snippet. This works however, if I first drag the snippet, then it shows up. But a fresh project, it just isn't showing up the first time.

Comment: Try it. Open a new iOS project, single view, in the (viewController.m) interface(), see if your snippet shortcut works.

Comment: It don't work now, maybe some Xcode cache was there, when I try change it from one scope to another. Sorry for confusing answer.

Comment: Hey Deny, not a problem, in fact, that was my point really, it seems that XCode is somewhat inconsistent on this. Maybe a bug really, I'll shoot a bug report to Apple.